# Why I can not call a function in JFrame to another JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have JFrame 1 name: `Main`have a function:

```
public void updateDataInTable(){
    //tb is table in JFrame 1
    tb.setRowCount(0);
    listEmp = list.returnList();
    for(Employee i : listEmp){
        tb.addRow(i.toObject());
    }
}
```

And JFrame 2 name `Add`have a button:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            Main main = new Main();
            main.updateDataInTable();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Add.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
       this.setVisible(false);
    }
```

But when i click button in JFrame 2, no thing is happen, `updateDataInTable();` has been call, but `table` in JFrame 1 is not change! Can you explain why? and help me fix it, thanks all

Comment: You haven't shown us enough code to be sure, but I suspect it is because you are creating a new Main object rather than using the existing one.

Comment: Yep, thanks you so much for idea!. I can fix this problem by pass JFrame1 to constructor of JFrame 2!

Comment: An application should not have multiple JFrames. Instead the child window should be a JDialog. And yes you would pass the JFrame reference to the constructor of the JDialog. In fact you create the dialog using the frame as the "parent".